# Submitting a form with the enter button in a form with several submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with a simple text field and multiple submit buttons. When the user presses enter, I want to submit the form with a specific submit button, but it looks like the form just chooses the first button instead. Is there any way to tell the browser which submit button to choose when user presses enter? Preferrably without javascript, but I'll take it if that's the only solution.

Edit: I have no other choice than having multiple submit buttons. This is a legacy app.

Comment: Why do you need several submit buttons?? what are you trying to do? maybe there's other way

Comment: Don't apologise for needing multiple submit buttons. It's a perfectly sound idea

Comment: especially since this appears to be the only way to figure out which button was clicked using MVC.NET

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no way. The simplest solution is just to ensure that the first submit button in the form is the one you want triggered by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.

Note that this submit button can be a duplicate of a button elsewhere in the form, and it doesn't have to be *visible*.

Comment: That was a neat trick. I used that, and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple JS to catch the onkeypress event:

```
onkeypress="if ((event.keyCode | event.which) == 13) { document.getElementById('MySubmitButton').click(); return false; }"
```

Just add this to the textbox tag and replace "MySubmitButton" with the ID of the desired submit button.

Note: use ID, not name.

Comment: Thanks ! I've been looking through different kinds of hacks for the past 30 minutes and this one is the best !

Answer (score 0):

If you had the following HTML

```
<form id="form_one">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit 1" />
</form>
<form id="form_two">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit 2" />
</form>
```

Then you could have a bit of jQuery as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == '13') {
            $("#form_one").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously you'd have to put in the logic to decide which form to submit.

Also as far as I know if a control in "form_one" had focus and you hit enter it would automatically submit that form the control is contained within.

Answer (score -1):

you can just define a javascript method on the "onclick" or "onkeypress" event of the button, from which u wanted to get the form submitted. But u have to define the process to occur in the javascript function