# How to choose which form button gets clicked (BY DEFAULT) when user presses enter?

Tags: html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Submitting a form with the enter button in a form with several submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068082/submitting-a-form-with-the-enter-button-in-a-form-with-several-submit-buttons)

I have an html form with two submit buttons.

How can I set the default button that is 'clicked' when a user presses enter whilst in said form?

As @quentin pointed out, the first button is used to submit when 'enter' is pressed...

So how would I make the 2nd button default for example?

**EDIT**: To clarify: Let's say there is a form that doubles as a login and registration form. THere are two buttons: one to register; one to sign up. What if I want the second button to be 'clicked' when the user presses enter?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the situation? Do you have something like `Promote | Demote | Cancel` in your submits, where the value of the submit is meaningful?

Comment: Two submit buttons? Why? When user presses enter, the form gets submitted, I don't think any of the buttons is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that button first (in browsers that will trigger any button when the form is submitted with enter (and set a default for when neither of the buttons is successul in your server side processor)).

Comment: Hmm (not sure (is that hard to read?)). LOL

Comment: Thanks, but how would i set the 2nd button as default for example?

Comment: @iight — You move it (in the source) so it is the first button.